# System.OutOfMemoryException when receiving an Image

Tags: c#, image, networking, out-of-memory, memorystream

I'm trying to transfer an image using tcp (NetworkStream) and memory stream.
I tried this code (client):

```
BinaryReader breader = new BinaryReader(stream);
                int ctBytes = breader.ReadInt32();
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(breader.ReadBytes(ctBytes));
                Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

and the exception happens in the 3rd line. Actually, this code is inside a loop and the exception isn't being thrown in the first iteration.
the server code (if needed):

```
BinaryWriter bWriter = new BinaryWriter(writer.BaseStream);
       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
       img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
       byte[] buffer = new byte[ms.Length];
       ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
       ms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
       bWriter.Write(buffer.Length);
       bWriter.Write(buffer);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running as a 32 bit, or 64 bit process? How long is the memory stream? Have you tried resetting the position within the stream?

Comment: I'm not sure, my PC is 64 bit but I don't know about the process... how can I check? And I haven't tried to reset the position, why should I? every iteration it creates a new memory stream.

Comment: are you releasing your resources?

Comment: how should I release resources? dispose? flush? something else?

Comment: You should not be using the `BinaryReader`. Reading your client code I see you are storing at least 3/4 copies of your file from your 4 lines of client code. First copy in your stream buffer. Second copy your implcite `byte[]`. Third copy `MemoryStream`. Fourth copy `Image`. Try using `Image.FromStream(stream)` instead.

Comment: By default VS creates "prefer 32 bit" binaries. You can configure your project to be 64 bit explicitly.

Comment: @Aron what do you mean? I used Image.FromStream()... Do you mean directly from the network stream?

Comment: Yeah...although really you might want to put a `BufferedStream` in the middle (which is in effect what you are trying to use the `MemoryStream` for).

Comment: so what is the difference between the BufferedStream and the MemoryStream? (I mean in my case)

Answer (score 0):

You need to dispose your resources:

```
using(BinaryWriter bWriter = new BinaryWriter(writer.BaseStream))
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
   byte[] buffer = new byte[ms.Length];
   ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
   ms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
   bWriter.Write(buffer.Length);
   bWriter.Write(buffer);
}
```

Through the `using` clause the resources are released at the end of the block.

You have to do the same thing at the client.

Comment: In your answer, you used the server's code. Should I do the same with the server AND the client?

Comment: yes you always need to dispose objects that implement `IDisposable`, otherwise you end up with a memory leak.

Comment: But now when I'm trying to access the stream, it is said to be disposed. (writer.BaseStream)